# Broken BootStrap Template MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to build a MVC master template and sub pages based on bootstrap.

Somehow I have managed to break it and I cannot work out what has happened.

My test site is at http://taxiroutemvc.azurewebsites.net/

Notice how the various sections don't align vertically?

I'm guessing either too many or too few divs or some class problem but I just cant find it.

Comment: When you use bootstrap grid scaffolding try to adjust your interior div's rather than adding styles to .row .span(in this case 4). I say this because you can add too much padding/margin to things which will jack with the scaffolding and gutters that are predefined and then your content won't fit which will give you the wrap you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap was not designed for you to add the `well` class on the same element as a `spanX`.  You want to nest a `<div>` with the `well` class inside of your `spanX`.

**Edit:**
Also, when using the fluid scaffolding, all your rows need to be `row-fluid`.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <form>
                <div class="row-fluid"> <!-- not just 'row' -->
                    <div class="span12" id="bingMap">
                        etc.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="well">
                <h3>We cover the following areas:</h3>
                <a href="\Home\?from=Cardiff">Cardiff</a> | <a href="\Home\?from=Barry">Barry</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just tried that. and published. doesn't seem to have made any difference :( refresh the site. I must have something else wrong somewhere.

Comment: it seems to point towards the html in the view. a sub page like http://taxiroutemvc.azurewebsites.net/Home/Contact/ seems to look ok?

Comment: @TrevorDaniel You've still got `class="well span12"` in a few places. Also, your nested rows need to also be `row-fluid`, not just `row`

Comment: @sunmpy you are my hero. ive fixed it. your help has been invaluable. try it now... http://taxiroutemvc.azurewebsites.net/